# "this initial value does not correspond to a stochastic node" in WinBugs

Tags: projection, bayesian, mcmc, winbugs, hierarchical-bayesian

I gave initial values for all the stochastic nodes, but WinBUGS still gives me the message that

> this initial value does not correspond to a stochastic nodes

What node I am missing here?

```
#Model
model 
{ 
for( i in 1 :N) { 
Y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau) 
Z[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau) 
mu[i] <- theta[1] + theta[2]* exp(-exp(-theta[3]*(x[i]-theta[4]))) 
} 
theta[1]<-1.8 
theta[2] ~ dnorm(0,0.01) 
theta[3] ~ dnorm(0,0.01) 
theta[4] ~ dnorm(0,0.01) 
tau ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001) 
sigma <- 1 / sqrt(tau) 
} 
#Data
list(x=c(1971,1976,1981,1986,1991,1996,2001,2006,2011,2016,2021,2026,2031,2036,2041,2046,2051,2056,2061),
Y=c(5.2,4.7,4.5,4.2,3.6,3.4,3.1,2.8,2.4,2.3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), N=19)
#Initial values
list(theta=c(0,0,0), tau=1)
```